# A regex that cannot match (for a generated expression)

Tags: python, regex

In my code I generate a regular expression from a list of subexpressions. Joining expressions works fine if I put each of them in a non-matching group `(?:…)`:

```
# concatenation:
joined_expr = ''.join('(?:{})'.format(expr) for expr in subexpression)
# disjunction:
joined_expr = '|'.join('(?:{})'.format(expr) for expr in subexpression)
```

Problem is: The result of this joined expression is a subexpression for a bigger expression, and `subexpression` could be empty, but the joined expression must not match the empty string.

So what would be the easiest why to make **a regular expression, that cannot match**? Would `(?:(?!.).)` work? If not, why not? Would Python's `re` engine understand my attempt to create a failing branch and optimize it?

Comment: Does it matter if it matches an empty string if it's marked as a non-capturing group?

Comment: `joined_expr` will be used in a concatenated expression, which is a branch of a disjunction. This branch must not match (i.e. is must fail). I used the word "match" as "does not fail" in here.

Comment: If you are looking to not do an operation on the resulting string if it's null, why not just skip the re and do `match = regex.match(string); if match & bool(string):   do_code`

It's way simpler and probably faster than checking for a null string via re for the combined condition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spare the time elapsed by the regex engine using:

```
 \Zx # or '$s' to match a literal after the end of the string
```

It much more simpler than `(?:(?!.).)` for long strings and you obtain the same result.

Here is a short online test with a text of `4231` chars:

- [Test negative lookahead](https://regex101.com/r/fE3iW4/1) - `(?:(?!.).)` - 16924 steps
- [Test after end anchor](https://regex101.com/r/fE3iW4/2) - `\Zx` - 2 steps

Comment: Wow, thank you! `\Zx` is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

One can use `(?!)` in engines that understand negated lookahead assertions. PCRE uses `(*FAIL)` as a more readable synonym.

> If you want to force a matching failure at some point in a pattern, the most convenient way to do it is with `(?!)` because an empty string always matches, so an assertion that requires there not to be an empty string must always fail. The backtracking control verb `(*FAIL)` or `(*F)` is a synonym for `(?!)`.
>
> -- http://www.pcre.org/current/doc/html/pcre2pattern.html